# Search in a graph of medical records

Tags: information-retrieval, igraph

I have a hierarchical order of a disease list. Just for example:

1. Respiratory system disease

   1.1.  Asphyxia neonatorum

   1.2.  Croup

   1.3.  Lower respiratory tract disease

   1.4.  Bronchial disease

   1.4.1.                    asthma

   1.4.2.                    bronchiectasis

   1.4.3.                    bronchitis

   1.5.  lung disease

   1.5.1.                    acute chest syndrome

   1.5.2.                    bronchiolitis

   1.5.3.                    brown induration

   1.6.  interstitial lung disease

   1.6.1.                    bronchiolitis obliterans

   1.6.2.                    extrinsic allergic alveolitis

   1.6.3.                    pneumoconiosis

Next, I have a database with people’s medical records.  For example:

Patient-1:   asthma, bronchiolitis

Patient-2:   asthma, pneumoconiosis

Lastly, when a new patient enters the system. For example:

Patient-to-search:   asthma, brown induration

I want to find the person which is “most similar” in terms of the  diseases hierarchy. (Which is Patient-1). How do I accomplish such task efficiently with the graph tool?

Comment: Do you already have a graph constructed?

Comment: If not, why do you think you need to use a graph structure? Do you have a "similarity metric" for measuring the similarity of patients?

Comment: I ask because simply finding nearest neighbors with `igraph` is a programming problem and so the post belongs on StackOverflow. But there could be statistical content here as well

Comment: Hi @Dov, you could try propensity score matching. I have used them in past to create pseudo test-control studies in observational databases similar to yours.

Comment: @ssdecontrol, thanks for your comment. No, I don't have a single line of code yet and neither a "similarity metric" this is all what I'm looking for... Why graph? Because it feels "right" to me in this case, I have a hierarchical order of a disease list (50K long) and only 2K of patient (sparse?) so I need to find similar cases based on the location in the graph hierarchy.

Comment: @Dov I see. So you could define distance between two disease states by the length of the shortest path between them in the disease hierarchy. Then it becomes a question of how to measure the distance between _patients_ when patients can have multiple disease states. Is that an accurate restatement of the problem? How many diseases can a patient have?

Comment: @ssdecontrol, Many thanks for your prompt response. Yes, this is an accurate description!  A patient (70+ year old) could have 7 to 10 different types of diseases.

Comment: @Dov the variable number of diseases makes it tricky. I'll do some digging because I'm interested but we definitely have a few users who know something about multivariate problems like this

Comment: Also @Dov you should absolutely edit those details into the body of the question

Comment: And by the way your graph approach is also known as a "concept hierarchy"

Comment: @ssdecontrol I think I have found something relevant http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1310/1310.1285.pdf

Comment: @Dov great find! Sections 5.5-5.9 should contain some kind of answer that can help you